# Could not receive AJAX POST data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post a variable as an object to my PHP file, but it doesn't receive any data. I tried `window.alert(u.un)` to test whether the data is being passed from AJAX call, and it works fine and there are no errors in my console. But still I'm not getting data in PHP file, there are no errors either.

This is my AJAX function

```
function getfulldetails(n)
{ 
var u={un:n};  window.alert(u.un);
var locationto= "getfull.php";
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: locationto,
   data: u,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   success: function(response)
      {
        window.alert(response);
      }
   });
   return false;
}
```

This is my PHP file

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST')
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST["un"]))
     {
        function validate_data($data)
        {
             require 'connectcred.php';
             $data = trim($data);
             $data = stripslashes($data);
             $data = strip_tags($data);
             $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
             $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data);
             return $data;    
        }
        $u=validate_data($_REQUEST["un"]);
        echo $u;
     }
     else
     {
         echo "something's wrong";
     }
}
?>
```

I'm getting result only from the `else` part.

I've used AJAX using the code below many times to get data from *Form* and it worked like a charm, but its not working when I assign an object myself.

Comment: What is your PHP version ?

Comment: look into `$_POST["un"]`

Comment: I'm using PHP v.7.1.11 (XAMPP server).

Comment: @maioman That doesn't work either, I tried several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set `Content-Type` / `contentType` to `false`. You also need to send an actual query string.

For now, this should fix it:

```
$.post(locationto, u, (response) => {
    window.alert(response);     
});
```

Alternatively, use `data: "un=" + n`

Also, in your PHP, use only `$_POST`.